# Apparmor KVM Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.10, kvm-virtualization, apparmor

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.  I am trying to install KVM guest.  When I try to do so with VNC I get following apparmor error in syslog:

```
kernel: [ 3016.448241] audit: type=1400 audit(1423018183.349:51): apparmor="DENIED" 
 operation="unlink" profile="libvirt-653f917e-53bc-4a3c-a354-567371473c96" name="/var/lib/libv
irt/qemu/ubuntuHA.vnc" pid=5503 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

here is my `virt-install`

```
virt-install  -n "ubuntuHA" --memory=2048 --vcpus 2  \
    --cdrom=/data/img/ubuntu_14.10.img --os-variant=ubuntuutopic  \
    --graphics none --virt-type kvm --disk path=/data/kvm/ubuntuha.img,bus=virtio,size=40  \
    --network network=default,model=virtio --network bridge=virbr0 \
    --graphics vnc,port=5901,password=*****
```

When I remove apparmor and reboot machine everything works fine; however with apparmor I get the above error every time.

Comment: As a less blunt workaround you can use [aa-complain](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/aa-complain.8.html) to put AppArmor in "complain" mode. This stops AppArmor from enforcing its policy, but lets it still make entries in the logs.